# Copy text/content from td to another td by condition

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html-table, copy

I would like to copy td to another td by condition. 
I do not want use some function on click or press key.. i need function on loading.
For example - Is in td id-'hello' character 1? If yes, move all content to td 'hello_copy' 

**`<td id="hello">`number 1 is good**`</td>`

```
<td id="hello_copy></td>
```

**RESULT:**

`<td id="hello">`number 1 is good`</td>`

```
<td id="hello_copy>`number 1 is good`</td>
```

Comment: there is no condition.. Only if in hello is number 1 so do copy

Comment: Excuse me,... I mean - if in the <td> you see "1" copy everything from <td> to another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the `:contains` selector to find out if there's a `1` in the text of the `#hello` cell, and then copy the value to the `#hello_copy` cell, like this:

```js
if ($('#hello:contains("1")'))
  $('#hello_copy').text($('#hello').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="hello">number 1 is good</td>
    <td id="hello_copy"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help